# Nativescript fallback exception when referencing external dependencies

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-vue

**Summary**

*Include details about your goal:*
I am attempting to include external libraries in a nativescript (vue) app; specifically openpgp

*Describe expected and actual results:*
Initially, I expected to be able to add the external library to package.json and proceed. Upon further reading I realize there are some dependancies which are not available (fs, path, crypto, etc.). Investigating this issue, I found [nodeify](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nodeify) however, this did not resolve my issue. I've also tried [node-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin) without success.

*Include any error messages:*
When not using nodeify/node-polyfill, I get 4 errors similar to this:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'PATH'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

The four libraries referenced in the exceptions are: 'os-browserify', 'browserify-zlib', 'crypto-browserify', 'stream-browserify'

When using node-polyfill my issue remains but the errors are semi-masked and look as follows:

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'fallback' of undefined
ERROR in Cannot read property 'fallback' of undefined
ERROR in Cannot read property 'fallback' of undefined
ERROR in Cannot read property 'fallback' of undefined
ERROR in Cannot read property 'fallback' of undefined
```

**What I've tried**

As mentioned, I've tried with and without nodeify and node-polyfill. When not using node-polyfill I have attempted to set fallback <s>however I am unsure of the [syntax](https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack.html#examples-of-configurations)</s>

*EDIT: proper syntax for setting fallback*

```
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");

module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

    // Learn how to customize:
    // https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack

    webpack.chainWebpack(config => {
        config.resolve.set('fallback', { 
            "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
            "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib"),
            "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            "util": require.resolve("util/"),
            "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/")
        });
    });

    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

The above code block resolves the build errors, however the following runtime errors occur

```
System.err: TypeError: util.inherits is not a function
.....
```

webpack.config.js (with node-polyfill):

```
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")


module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

    // Learn how to customize:
    // https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack

    webpack.chainWebpack(config => {
        config.resolve.plugin('polyfills').use(NodePolyfillPlugin);
    });


    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

**Reproduce issue**

```
ns create <project-name> --vue //effects --ts as well
```

```
npm install openpgp
```

Include require/import in script section

```
import * as openpgp from 'openpgp';
```

**Related articles**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478500

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71567424

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64580815

**Other considerations:**

I've read downgrading to webpack 4 (4.1.0) may resolve this; in updating package.json I updated the webpack.conig.js:

```
./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs
```

When doing so I get the following:

```
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/[user]/projects/android/[project]/webpack.config.js',
    '/home/[user]/projects/android/[project]/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js',
    '/home/[user]/projects/android/[project]/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/home/[user]/projects/android/[project]/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
```

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve your issue? Seems I faced the similar one and got stuck with it

Comment: Unfortunatly I did not. My solution ended up being abandoning pgp encryption altogether and using an existing nativescript library with ssl encryption; NativeScript-HTTPS. Good luck.